# App cannot gather column names from the db

Tags: delphi, odbc, ado

I have the following construction
Delphi Form > ADO Connection > Otero ODBC Driver > RBase database

(ignore please exotic names)

From the user's logic side, it's all classic:
ADO Connection > ADO Query > DataSource > DBGrid

This construction works perfectly on majority of the machines, but one.
On the machine, when it does not work as expected, ADO return columns descriptions instead of columns names.

Normally it's like this

```
Select * from SystemUsers
```

```
 SystemUserId SystemUserName                                               
 ------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ 
            1 Administrator
```

but on the problematic machine I'm getting

```
 SystemUserId System Autonumber Numero unico de identificacao da Collection FK
 ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ 
                              1 Administrator
```

The problematic system is Windows 2019 - but on other Windows 2019 the same app works well. I can take the app ape copy to any other machine, and it works as expected. The machine has installed the same version of the DB and ODBC driver.

As effect, when I call

```
myAdoQuery.FieldByName('SystemUserId').asInteger ....
```

I'm getting error:

> Field SystemUserId does not exist

I tried naming columns

```
Select SystemUserId as mycolumn from SystemUsers
```

... no luck

I tried adding fields to Fields editor - same effect.

I could call fields by its indexes (Field[i]), but this mean re-engineering entire app.

Does anybody know what could go wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out, that there was a difference in database server versions (I thought it was the same, but there was a difference). We have updated it and all the problems vanished.

thank you all